# Incomplete html from Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, screen-scraping

Hi I was wondering why if I have a certain page's url and use selenium like this:

```
webdriver.get(url)
webdriver.page_source
```

The source code given by selenium lacks elements that are there when inspecting the page from the browser ?

Is it some kind of way the website protects itself from scraping ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some delay between `webdriver.get(url)` and `webdriver.page_source` to let the page completely loaded

Answer (score 0):

Generally it should give you entire page source content with all the tags and tag attributes. But this is only `applicable for static web pages` .

for dynamic web pages, `webdriver.page_source` will only give you page resource whatever is available at that point of time in DOM. cause DOM will be updated based on user interaction with page.

Note that **iframes** are excluded from `page_source` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

If the site you are scraping is a **Dynamic website**, then it takes some time to load as the JavaScript should run, do some DOM manipulations etc., and only after this you get the source code of the page.

So it is better to add some time delay between your `get` request and getting the page source.

```
import time

webdriver.get(url)

# pauses execution for x seconds.
time.sleep(x)

webdriver.page_source
```

Comment: you can not get ` the complete source code of the page.` in case if it is Dynamic website

Comment: @cruisepandey By "complete" - I meant the source code after DOM manipulations and not the code that gets changed on user activity.

Answer (score 0):

The page source might contain one link on javascript file and you will see many controls on the page that has been generated on your side in your browser by running js code.

The source page is:

```
<script>
[1,2,3,4,5].map(i => document.write(`<p id="${i}">${i}</p>`))
</script>
```

Virtual DOM is:

```
<p id="1">1</p>
<p id="2">2</p>
<p id="3">3</p>
<p id="4">4</p>
<p id="5">5</p>
```

To get Virtual DOM HTML:

```
document.querySelector('html').innerHTML
```

```html
<script>
[1,2,3,4,5].map(i => document.write(`<p id="${i}">${i}</p>`))
console.log(document.querySelector('body').innerHTML)
</script>
```

> 